# What is the distribution of x (P(X=x))?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider drawing balls, one at a time, without replacement, from an urn containing M balls, K of which are defective. Let the random variable X(Y) denote the number of the draw on which the first defective (nondefective) ball is obtained. Let Z denote the number of the draw On which the rth defective ball is obtained.

My problem is that I don't know what this notation X(Y) means, does it mean that Y is contained in X?

because later it asks me for the joint f(x, y), so X and Y are two different variables

Comment: it means X is the number of the draw on which the first defective ball is obtained, and Y is the number of the draw on which the first nondefective ball is obtained.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a second option in parentheses is another way of saying “respectively”. The second sentence of your question is equivalent to:

> Let the random variables $X$ and $Y$ denote the numbers of the draws on which the first defective ball and the first nondefective ball, respectively, are obtained.

That is, $X$ is the number of the draw on which the first defective ball is obtained, and $Y$ is the number of the draw on which the first non-defective ball is obtained.